# Using awk on a CSV to find date pattern in first column

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, command-line-interface

I'm trying to do some data manipulation on a directory of CSVs I have.

I want to append all the rows in any CSV file where the first column matches a date pattern to a file called 'SUMMARY.csv'. For instance, I want all the rows that have a March date in the first column. Columns contain dates in MM/DD/YYYY format.

*DATA EXAMPLE:*

```
03/01/2017, "X AuD, Y", "First Last", "X MD, Y", "Loc"
02/04/2017, "X AuD, Y", "First Last", "X MD, Y", "Loc"
01/03/2017, "X AuD, Y", "First Last", "X MD, Y", "Loc"
```

*AWK EXAMPLE:*

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ "03\\/*\\/*" {print}' *.csv >> SUMMARY.csv
```

*EXPECTED RESULTS:*

```
03/01/2017, "X AuD, Y", "First Last", "X MD, Y", "Loc"
```

***ACTUAL RESULTS:***

```
03/01/2017, "X AuD, Y", "First Last", "X MD, Y", "Loc"
01/03/2017, "X AuD, Y", "First Last", "X MD, Y", "Loc"
```

For some reason, I can't get it to reliably pull only rows where the MONTH is equal to what I'm putting into the awk statement.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! Been on this one for a few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing an anchor to the start of the field, so a `03` elsewhere is matching. Also, you're using `*` incorrectly, so actually you're making the `/`s optional.

Try this instead:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /^03/' *.csv
```

For your data, it should be sufficient. `{ print }` happens by default. Note that I'm using a literal regular expression inside `/` rather than a string inside `"`, which awk then has to compile.

In fact, you can go even simpler, since you're matching the first field:

```
awk -F, '/^03/' *.csv
```

But by this point it looks more like a job for grep:

```
grep '^03' *.csv
```

---

This works for the first field but remember that awk and grep are not CSV parsers, so once you start having to do more complex things like read inside the quoted fields (which could contain commas), you should be using a proper parser.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! So, I took your suggestion and tried using `awk -F, '$1 ~ /^03/' *.csv`. This didn't work which is strange becuase the value are infact MM/dd/yyyy. I can get it to work by using `awk -F, '$1 ~ /^3/' *.csv` which returns only matches with month '03' BUT it only goes through the first CSV in the directory. which is weird because I'm using *.csv which I think would get me everything. Any ideas?

Comment: @EliSobylak the problem you describe having is 100% impossible to have given what you've told us so far. So, there's something else you haven't told us about yet. Create a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem and post a new question since Toms answer answers your original quetsion.

Comment: @EdMorton You're right. After some playing around, I've discovered that it's only using the awk command on files if I open them and click save. After I re-save them, awk picks them up. Wonder why this might be...

Comment: There's something wrong with your initial file and your editor is fixing it on the fly. Try `head -5 file | cat -v` on the file before/after the save to see what the editor is changing.

Comment: You're right again. The output is different after I save the file and use your command to read out the first 5 lines. After the file is saved, some quotes around strings are gone and every line ends with '^M'. hmmmm

Answer (score 0):

Added the `starts with (^)` expression. Else, it will match 03 anywhere in the `$1` field:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ "^03" {print}' *.csv >> SUMMARY.csv
```

Comment: The regular expression delimiter is `/`, the string delimiter is `"`. For efficiency, simplicity, and robustness use the regular expression delimiter for regexps unless you NEED to create a dynamic regexp from strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
awk -F'[/]' '$1 == 03' f
03/01/2017, "X AuD, Y", "First Last", "X MD, Y", "Loc"
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that reproducing the desired output isn't the only thing that makes a useful answer. Your regular expression makes no sense and you have provided no explanation of the changes you've made to the OP's attempt.